# Creating LLVMTargetMachineRef from C API

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-c++-api

Digging through the source of [lli](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/tools/llc/llc.cpp) which uses the LLVM C++ API, I can clearly follow, how to construct a TargetMachine ([L342](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/tools/llc/llc.cpp#L342)). It uses the cpu and features strings obtained from calls to the respective support functions ([L322](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/tools/llc/llc.cpp#L322)).

How is this accomplished using just the C API?

Comment: The support functions [don't do a lot of work](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/aef5f640f7803f6daaf550ec9d44b70e232decee/include/llvm/CodeGen/CommandFlags.h#L320). What are you currently able to get and what are you still missing?

Comment: I am still missing the CPU and feature strings. You are right, the support wrappers don't do much. But the calls to the respective functions in https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Support/Host.cpp do. I don't want to reimplement this.

Comment: What kind of TargetMachine do you want to create? Are you just looking for a native x86 TargetMachine or something else?